# Circumstances under which a windows server login becomes disabled

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, security

Can anyone confirm under what circumstances a SQL Server windows login account changes from Enabled to Disabled?

More specifically does this need to be a human interaction or can SQL Server automatically disable a windows account under some circumstances (say if it connects too frequently?)

I do not have access to the SQL Server logs so I can't check these

We have many SSIS jobs running against many SQL Servers under a service account. We discovered yesterday that the windows account was disabled on one source server (but still functions against many other servers)

Update: its possible this account was not disabled but I'm still interested in the answer.

Comment: Only a human intervention can change it or query which was running as part of some process it cannot do by its own. See errorlogs you would get information there

Comment: Thanks. I don't have access to error logs but that clarifies it for me. Do you want to put that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server never automatically disables any account. Only a human intervention can do that....

Probably you could put a request for your DBA to provide error logs for the timings you wanted....and you could find the info from the logs....